# How do I implement a Changed event if I only have some limited events available?

Tags: c#, wpf

I know the following code has too bad design to see, but I must implement the event on limited Framework invented by some vendor.

I'm dealing with a ***Control***
such as ***UserControl*** which has many ***TextBox*** Control.

The UserControl is like an Excel provided by the vendor.

This Control has the following **Events**.

> ***"CellBeginEdit"*** ... When you've focused the control, it fires.
>
> ***"CellEditEnded"*** ... When you've focused other controls, it fires.
>
> ***"CellEditEnding"*** ... When you focus other controls, it fires.
>
> ***"CellEnter"*** ... When you focus the cell in the control, it fires.
>
> ***"CellLeave"*** ... When you focus other cells in the control, it fires.

That's all events for editing ***Text*** in the ***Cell***.

However I need to implement ***TextChanged*** Event in all cells.

This is my code.

```
    private void CellBeginEdit(object sender, CellBeginEditEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the element before Editing 
        Cell cell = currentCell;        
    
        //Not show. it requires to fire TextChanged event when textBox.Text = "something"; 
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.Text = cell.Text;

        textBox.TextChanged += (s, ev) => MessageBox.Show("Done!");

        cell.Text = "Another Value";

        //I wish This code emerges "Done!" on Message Box.
    }
```

I tried to do, but it didn't work well.

I've already known ***string*** worked as if Primitive Type did in that case and C#,

So I re-written the above to the following.

```
    public TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    private void changeData(ref string data)
    {
        textBox.Text = data;
    }

    private void CellBeginEdit(object sender, CellBeginEditEventArgs e)
    {
        Cell cell = currentCell;

        changeData(ref cell.Text);

        textBox.TextChanged += (s, ev) => MessageBox.Show("hoge");

        cell.Text = "Another Value";
    }
```

However these code causes compilation error.

It said I couldn't use `ref` keyword with the Property.

Why can't I place the `ref` here? And how do I implement the Event?

**Edit:**

Thank you ! I perfectly solved.
This is the code.

```
        new Thread(
            delegate() {
                while (true)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.RowCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (sheet.Cells[i, 4].Text != "Before Value")
                        {
                            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                new Action(
                                    () =>
                                      sheet.Cells[i, 5].Background = Brushes.Azure
                                )
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
        ).Start();
```

Comment: `System.String` *is* a Reference Type - and do not confuse `ref` with Reference Types! It is also immutable, but that doesn't change the previous fact. To get a better response to this question start over - reset the assumption and remove the unneeded commentary. Focus on and explain the *actual problem* at hand as *succinctly as possible*. (And also remove the extra blank lines, too-much vertical is hard for me to follow along.)

Comment: Sorry and I know that. But I cannot find proper words.

Comment: Isn't the problem just "How do I create a TextChanged event if I only have some CellBegin/EndEdit events available?"

Comment: @Dirk That's right. Thanks. I'll edit the title sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work, as strings are immutable.

Your problem isn't that you don't get a reference to the string, because you already do. The problem is that the string will never change. When the text in the cell changes, it won't change the string that holds the text, it will create a new string with the changed text and use that instead.

The possible ways that I see to create a `TextChanged` event for the control would be either to use reflection to hack into the private members of the class, or using a timer to periodically check the `Text` property of the control to see if it has changed.

Comment: Thank you!! It indicates for me to solve the problem. I'll try to do that. I've completely forgotten existing reflection.